# Servlet receives empty object from Remote EJB3 Session Bean

Tags: servlets, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, stateless-session-bean

I'm sure this is a beginner error...

So I have a Java EE 6 application with entities, facades (implementing the persistence layer) and Stateless Session Beans (EJB3) with Remote interfaces (providing access to the entities via facades).

This is working fine. Via the SLSB I can retrieve and manipulate entities.

Now, I'm trying to do this from a Web Application (deployed on the same Glassfish, entity+interface definitions from Java EE app imported as separate jar). I have a Servlet, that receives an instance of the SLSB injected. I get it to retrieve an entity, and the following happens (I can see it in the logs):

- the remote SLSB gets instantiated, its method called
- SLSB instantiates the facade, calls the 'get' method
- facade retrieves instance of entity from DB, returns it
- SLSB returns the instance of the entity to the caller

  - *(all is good until here)*
- calling servlet receives .. an **empty instance** of the entity !!

What is going wrong? This should work, right?

MyServlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @EJB
  private CampaignControllerRemote campaignController; // remote SLSB

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
      Campaign c = campaignController.getCampaign(5L); // id of an existing campaign
      out.println("Got "+ c.getSomeString()); // is null !!
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

*Pls let me know if you want to see other code, and I'll update the post.*

Comment: Is c null object or getsomestring returns empty?
Did the logs show the '5L' campaign fully populated in the SLSB before call returns to servlet?

Comment: @josek: `c` exists, is not null. `c.getSomeString()` returns null. When the SLSB retrieves the '5L' campaign, `someString` is properly populated.

Comment: i might be wrong, but think glassfish needs the remote interfaces packaged in same webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... oh boy, this is sort of embarrassing ...

It turns out, I have been ignoring a nice little warning regarding the use of `Vector` as type of a field that holds a `@xxToMany` relationship with `FetchType.LAZY`:

> Element [field someField] within
>   entity class [class Campaign] uses a
>   collection type [class
>   java.util.Vector] when the JPA
>   specification only supports
>   java.util.Collection, java.util.Set,
>   java.util.List, or java.util.Map. 
>   This type is supported with eager
>   loading; using lazy loading with this
>   collection type requires additional
>   configuration and an IndirectContainer
>   implementation that extends [class
>   java.util.Vector] or setting the
>   mapping to use basic indirection and
>   the type to be ValueholderInterface.

Two possible solutions can fix my behaviour:

- use `FetchType.EAGER` (then I could stay with `Vector`)
- use `List` (as the spec says...)